# Using PHP, how to parse the title and meta tags from a HTML page?

Tags: php, html-parsing, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter: A Class/Library to help get meta tags from a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273555/codeigniter-a-class-library-to-help-get-meta-tags-from-a-web-page)

I need to be able to get the TITLE and DESCIPTION metadata out of a page.

I've been trying to do this but I've been getting more errors than actual results. (I have an array of about 10 URLS, usually only about 2 of them give me the descrption. I have yet to get the title).

So how do I, in PHP, get the Desc and Title from a remote page, and if there is none or if there's an error, ignore it?

-Dylan

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273555/codeigniter-a-class-library-to-help-get-meta-tags-from-a-web-page

Comment: +1 for not trying to use regular expressions to solve this. SO will thank you for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like cURL (Checking things like the result isn't false and that the HTTP status is 200) to get the page and then [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse it and extract the elements you want. (Remembering that the elements might not exist)