# how to parse the meta tag in the webpage

Tags: php, meta-tags, robots.txt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter: A Class/Library to help get meta tags from a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273555/codeigniter-a-class-library-to-help-get-meta-tags-from-a-web-page)

can any body write a simple prog for retreiving the out put as found or not found 
for metatags,alltags,robots.txt file

```
<?php 
$url = 'example.com'; 
$meta = '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'; 
$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
if(strpos($contents, $meta) !== false) 
{ 
    echo 'found'; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'not found'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: its a program that should retreive found or nt found drm the desired web page..!!!in php script

Comment: Uhm.. What have you tried? SO is a Q&A site, not a "do my work for me" site.

Comment: i have tried by using strpos but its not wrking for few sites so had a query on that

Comment: Post your code.. You're bound to get a *lot* more help that way rather than asking people to write it *for* you.

Comment: <?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$meta = '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(strpos($contents, $meta)!== false) {
echo 'found';
} else {
echo 'not found';
}

Comment: this is the program i have written

Comment: <?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$meta = 'alt';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
if(strpos($contents, $meta)!== false) {
echo 'found';
} else {
echo 'not found';
} 
?>

Comment: this is the program in the wesite in <img src if alt tag is present then it should show found or else not found but it is showing found as default is the code correct plz rectify the error if posibble

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Use **[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php)** to retrieve raw HTML data
2. **[Tidy](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/tidy.examples.php)** the HTML code to make it more readable; if Tidy is not installed on your web server:

   apt-get install php5-tidy
3. Parse the  ellement with **[DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.domdocument-get-elements-by-tagname.php)**

Comment: @creadiff thanku for the clear idea buddy can u give me the code for that one as i have tried many times but its not coming..

Comment: You have all the right elements! Why don't you at least give it a try?

Comment: can u plz check the above code and let me know if possible plz...

Comment: This code would only work in rare occasions, since the string you are looking for is very specific.

Comment: oh k ya i know bt its too dificult its working in a specific site and not exe in other site

Comment: any way thanx for the code and helpin me our bro...!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_meta($url)
{
    // Get & Tidy HTML
    $tidy = new tidy();
    $tidy->parseFile($url, array("output-html" => true));
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    // Parse XML
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadHTML($tidy);
    $meta_tags = $xml->getElementsByTagName("meta");
    // Put meta informations in an array
    $meta = array();
    foreach($meta_tags as $meta_tag)
    {
        $key = $meta_tag->hasAttribute("http-equiv") ? $meta_tag->getAttribute("http-equiv") : $meta_tag->getAttribute("name");
        $value = $meta_tag->hasAttribute("content") ? $meta_tag->getAttribute("content") : $meta_tag->getAttribute("value");
        $meta[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $meta;
}

print_r(get_meta("http://php.net/manual/fr/tidy.cleanrepair.php"));
```

Comment: In the above code u mentioned where should i pass the url of the webiste...?what is the correct way in for each or in $url?

Comment: $url contains the URL of the web page you want to parse, in string format. The function returns an associative array of the meta tag, which you can check using the **print_r** function:

http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/function.print-r.php

Comment: how to pass the url in the above code correctly can u guide me

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpfunctions.php

Comment: i have passed the url in the above code but it is showing the syntax error:-(

Comment: I just edited the above code.

Comment: @creadiff:its not working where should i pass the url of the website

Comment: @creadiff:it is showing this error msg

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'tidy' not found in E:\www\seo\untitled.php on line 15

Comment: As I said before, you need to install the tidy extension for PHP on your web server: **apt-get install php5-tidy**