# Fetching "property og" meta tags from URL with PHP

Tags: php, url, fetch, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I want to create a posting feature similar to the one Facebook uses (You paste a link into textbox, hit post and it posts a title, description and an image). I realized that it is best to extract the meta tags that have og properties such as "og:title" and "og:image" because if I use normal  tags, sometimes they have line breaks and such other things and it comes out with errors.

Is there a way to fetch contents of these tags using PHP, but without AJAX or other custom parsers? The starting point would be:

```
<?php

$url = $_POST['link'];

?>
```

We get the URL from the previous page through POST method, but how to do the rest?

Answer (score 9):

The solution is this:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$c = file_get_contents("http://url/here");
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:title']") as $el) {
    echo $el->getAttribute("content");
}
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:description']") as $el) {
    echo $el->getAttribute("content");
}
```

Comment: it's xpath, do it at once, not for twice: `//meta[@property='og:title' or @property='og:description']/@content`

Comment: if the document is not valid this throws an exception, and I would use a simple regex to get that instead of parsing the complete document

Comment: This worked perfectly, it's exactly what I have been searching for!

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like the below:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Yeah if you are so worried about using @ with warnings
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
$metas = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
    $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    $rmetas[$property] = $content;
}
var_dump($rmetas);
```

Found this on [How to get Open Graph Protocol of a webpage by php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454644/how-to-get-open-graph-protocol-of-a-webpage-by-php) - search is helpful, as is Google!

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=meta+property+og+tags

Comment: where do I put the URL variable in this? $html or $doc?

Comment: I should think $html ;) $doc is OOP

Comment: It's constantly giving me "Undefined variable: rmetas in C:\xampp\htdocs\linkedit\index.php on line 73
NULL"
Line 73 is var_dump($rmetas);

Comment: never mind, found out, the best way to do this is similar to the one you posted it can be found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273555/codeigniter-a-class-library-to-help-get-meta-tags-from-a-web-page) under Artefacto's post (4th answer), the only thing is you have to change name='keywords' to property='og:title' and it works perfectly

Comment: Feel free to tick the accept answer button or post your solution as an answer for future reference if someone stumbles across your question :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this: https://github.com/baj84/MetaData

It's easy and efficient.

```
$metaData = MetaData::fetch($url);
var_dump($metaData->tags());
```

Comment: this doesn't always work.  It returned no tags for me on twitter pages.

Answer (score 1):

We use **Apache Tika** via php (command line utility) with -j for json :

http://tika.apache.org/

```
<?php
    shell_exec( 'java -jar tika-app-1.4.jar -j http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying' );
?>
```

This is a sample **output** from a random guardian article :

```
{
   "Content-Encoding":"UTF-8",
   "Content-Length":205599,
   "Content-Type":"text/html; charset\u003dUTF-8",
   "DC.date.issued":"2013-07-21",
   "X-UA-Compatible":"IE\u003dEdge,chrome\u003d1",
   "application-name":"The Guardian",
   "article:author":"http://www.guardian.co.uk/profile/nicholaswatt",
   "article:modified_time":"2013-07-21T22:42:21+01:00",
   "article:published_time":"2013-07-21T22:00:03+01:00",
   "article:section":"Politics",
   "article:tag":[
      "Lynton Crosby",
      "Health policy",
      "NHS",
      "Health",
      "Healthcare industry",
      "Society",
      "Public services policy",
      "Lobbying",
      "Conservatives",
      "David Cameron",
      "Politics",
      "UK news",
      "Business"
   ],
   "content-id":"/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "dc:title":"Tory strategist Lynton Crosby in new lobbying row | Politics | The Guardian",
   "description":"Exclusive: Firm he founded, Crosby Textor, advised private healthcare providers how to exploit NHS \u0027failings\u0027",
   "fb:app_id":180444840287,
   "keywords":"Lynton Crosby,Health policy,NHS,Health,Healthcare industry,Society,Public services policy,Lobbying,Conservatives,David Cameron,Politics,UK news,Business,Politics",
   "msapplication-TileColor":"#004983",
   "msapplication-TileImage":"http://static.guim.co.uk/static/a314d63c616d4a06f5ec28ab4fa878a11a692a2a/common/images/favicons/windows_tile_144_b.png",
   "news_keywords":"Lynton Crosby,Health policy,NHS,Health,Healthcare industry,Society,Public services policy,Lobbying,Conservatives,David Cameron,Politics,UK news,Business,Politics",
   "og:description":"Exclusive: Firm he founded, Crosby Textor, advised private healthcare providers how to exploit NHS \u0027failings\u0027",
   "og:image":"https://static-secure.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pixies/2013/7/21/1374433351329/Lynton-Crosby-008.jpg",
   "og:site_name":"the Guardian",
   "og:title":"Tory strategist Lynton Crosby in new lobbying row",
   "og:type":"article",
   "og:url":"http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "resourceName":"tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "title":"Tory strategist Lynton Crosby in new lobbying row | Politics | The Guardian",
   "twitter:app:id:googleplay":"com.guardian",
   "twitter:app:id:iphone":409128287,
   "twitter:app:name:googleplay":"The Guardian",
   "twitter:app:name:iphone":"The Guardian",
   "twitter:app:url:googleplay":"guardian://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "twitter:card":"summary_large_image",
   "twitter:site":"@guardian"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..
it worked for me..

```
foreach($linkHtml->find('head meta[property=og:url]') as $url)
{   
    echo $url->content.'</br>';
}
```